# How to make simple form responsive using buttons

Tags: sapui5

I have made a simple form with one input field and two buttons as defined below:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
        xmlns="sap.m"
        xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
        xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
        controllerName="com.techmo.controller.Table"
        xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
        <Page
            class="employePageBackGroundColor"
            showHeader="false">
            <f:SimpleForm
                    id="EmployeeSimpleForm"
                    editable="true"
                    layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                    labelSpanL="4"
                    labelSpanM="4"
                    labelSpanS="6"
                    adjustLabelSpan="True"
                    emptySpanL="0"
                    emptySpanM="0"
                    emptySpanS="6"
                    columnsL="1"
                    columnsM="1"
                    singleContainerFullSize="false" >
                <f:content>
                        <Label text="Employee Name" reqiured="true">
                                    <layoutData>
                                        <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
                                    </layoutData>
                                </Label>
                                <Input id="empname">
                                    <layoutData>
                                        <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
                                    </layoutData>
                                </Input>
```

If i add buttons here it is not responsive in mobile view buttons are truncating and getting into next line. I am new to ui5  can anyone help me in solving this issue thanks in advance

```
 <Button class="search" type="Emphasized" text="Search" press="onSearch" icon="sap-icon://search">
                          <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
                          </layoutData>
             </Button>

     <Button class="userAddButton" text="ADD" press="onAddCustomer" icon="sap-icon://add-employee">
                <layoutData>
                   <l:GridData span="L5 M2 S12"/>
                 </layoutData>
      </Button>
</f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
```

Comment: For Mobile devices you need buttons in next line to each other OR both the buttons in different rows? If possible share the UI layout(screenshot) for better understanding.

Comment: This is my UI layout if we see it in mobile view i want to get search button beside input field https://ibb.co/JxDtdLF

Comment: So you need label, input and button in the same line?

Comment: yes when i minimize and see in mobile view all 3( i.e., input field and 2 buttons) should appear in same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding I have two answers for your question

**Buttons are next to each other**

```
<Button class="search" type="Emphasized" text="Search" press="onSearch" icon="sap-icon://search">
  <layoutData> <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S6"/> </layoutData>
</Button>
<Button class="userAddButton" text="ADD" press="onAddCustomer" icon="sap-icon://add-employee">
  <layoutData> <l:GridData span="L5 M2 S6"/> </layoutData>
</Button>
```

[image]

**Buttons in different line/rows**

```
<Button class="search" type="Emphasized" text="Search" press="onSearch" icon="sap-icon://search">
  <layoutData> <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/> </layoutData>
</Button>
<Button class="userAddButton" text="ADD" press="onAddCustomer" icon="sap-icon://add-employee">
  <layoutData> <l:GridData span="L5 M2 S12"/> </layoutData>
</Button>
```

[image]

**Input and Buttons in same line/rows**

```
<Label text="Employee Name">
  <layoutData> <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/> </layoutData>
</Label>                 
<Input id="empname">
  <layoutData> <l:GridData span="L6 M6 S4"/> </layoutData>
</Input>
<Button class="search" type="Emphasized" text="Search" press="onSearch" icon="sap-icon://search" >
  <layoutData> <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S4"/> </layoutData>
</Button>
<Button class="userAddButton" text="ADD" press="onAddCustomer" icon="sap-icon://add-employee">
  <layoutData> <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S4"/> </layoutData>
</Button>
```

[image]

Note: Mobile with smallest screen resolutions like iPhone 5/SE, the buttons text will truncate. Solution will be just to show the icon without text.

**Complete code**

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="com.techmo.controller.ManageEmployee"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page
        class="employePageBackGroundColor"
        showHeader="false">
        <f:SimpleForm
            id="EmployeeSimpleForm"
            editable="true"
            layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
            labelSpanL="4"
            labelSpanM="4"
            labelSpanS="6"
            adjustLabelSpan="True"
            emptySpanL="0"
            emptySpanM="0"
            emptySpanS="0"
            columnsL="1"
            columnsM="1"
            singleContainerFullSize="false" >
            <f:content>
                <Label text="Employee Name">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="empname" >
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L6 M6 S4"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Button  class="search" type="Emphasized" text="Search" press="onSearch" icon="sap-icon://search" >
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S4"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Button>
                <Button class="userAddButton" text="ADD" press="onAddCustomer" icon="sap-icon://add-employee">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S4"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Button>
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>         
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: I tried as you mentioned but it appears like this https://ibb.co/285Hsh5 when i view it in desktop and   for mobile view it appears like this https://ibb.co/fxpkTr3

Comment: I have updated the code and it will work proper in Desktop view. As per the mobile view is concerned there is not enough space to show both icon and the text, that's why the text is truncating. You can just show the icons in the mobile view

Comment: Thanks for all but one more issue i found was when viewing in iphone 6/7/8/x text in the button is truncating like this https://ibb.co/jyp9zxv

Comment: Not only the text but also the input is truncating.Some layout issue it is. Kindly share the complete layout to investigate. Its happening in the desktop view as well as per your previous shared screenshot.

Comment: The code which you have sent is only the SF code, which we have already discussed. I was talking about the compete layout inside which the SF is written, the complete XML view. I think due to some extra padding/margin it is getting truncated from the outer layout of SF.

Comment: also i have table in the view , https://www.codepile.net/pile/Vp8gaMKG let me know if this is sufficient

Comment: Look into [My Pile](https://www.codepile.net/pile/q3znqA3J), I have updated the code. Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot and when we view it in mobile the table is not responsive so for that in table we need to remove width and add fixed layout="false" it works responsive

Comment: Great!!  If I have answered your question, kindly accept

Comment: In the same way i have tried to add two separate forms in one page (one form with labels and inputs and the other form with labels and selected box )but  its not responsive can i know where i did mistake https://www.codepile.net/pile/k5wmo6qX